# How low will a given string hang?

Tags: mathematical-physics, hyperbolic-geometry

If I have a piece of string that is `n` meters long, attached at two points `m` meters apart, how low will the string hang?

The two points are at the same elevation, earth gravity, string is constant weight, and the string is long enough to reach the points.

#### Background:

I'm trying to have some draping canopy custom made, and I want to provide exact measurements so they don't hang down too far (and obstruct a door), but they also have some nice drape to them.  It's prohibitively difficult to get up there to mock it up and measure in situ.

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/114591/what-is-the-shape-of-a-rope-hanging-from-two-ends

Comment: Look up "catenary"

Comment: @cpiegore: Ummmmm, I tried asking people who are better at math than I am. :-)  More details added to question.  Ultimately, I'm just looking for the right formula so I can plug in my distances and tune things appropriately.

Comment: Gee guys, now this is a guy actually asking how to derive the equation of a catenary from the data he has (from which the sag is easily determined); a perfectly valid math question if you ask me.